# tagging (metadata) software

Tags: linux, tags

I am looking for software (preferred open source) that can handle tags and metadata for external objects.

The use case is like this:
I have software that saves some data and each data (files like) contain a unique id.
I need software that let the user add set and view tags to specific object from the first project.
The operating system is Linux but if there is only a Windows solution it will be also great.

The requirements are:

- Can manage tags and metadata for external objects.
- free (open source is preferred)
- API that will allow me to connect the original software ids.

Will really help:

- Allow managing the object in some kind of hierarchy (path-like). also, it will be nice if it will have something like a link (soft and hard link in a file system).
- Easy API
- web-based

Comment: What kind of objects you talk about?

Comment: I don’t want the other software to assume anything about the external object besides that they have unique ids. Nevertheless, the objects contain (right now, as it may be more in the future) files that are not saved as is in the FS and some more fields that describes the files (basically each object is a byte stream and JSON document with id)